# What is the most concise way to disable tracing before echo and enable it afterwards in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

So right now I am doing this:

```
set +x
echo ....
echo ....
set -x
```

I wonder if there is some way to do it "automagically"? Because the current pattern produces quite ugly code like this:

```
PS4='##[command]' ; set -x
#
# Some code
#
set +x
echo bla bla bla
set -x

if [[ ... ]]; then
  #
  # Some code
  #
  set +x
  echo bla bla
  set -x
else
  #
  # Some code
  #
  set +x
  echo bla bla
  set -x
fi
```

Is there a more elegant way to do it?

Comment: Do any of the answers to [this Unix & Linux question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/725160/temporarily-unset-bash-option-x) do what you want?

Comment: The second answer about `cleanecho` does it. Need to test it.